# Arguments in React Native Methods

Tags: javascript, react-native

This is a sample code i am trying to understand.

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       input: ''
     }
  }

handleChangeInput = (text) => {
    this.setState({ input: text })
  }

  render () {
    const { input } = this.state

    return (
       <View>
          <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={this.handleChangeInput}
            value={input}
          />
        </View>
      )
    }
 }
```

In this the code that is troubling me is

> onChangeText={this.handleChangeInput}

In this piece of code, there is no argument passed to the method(handleChangeInput) which expects text.

Can someone please throw a light here.

Comment: Actually that's not a method call, but specification of [_React event handler_](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) which doesn't expect any arguments passed (nor call parens at all). It expects _function reference_, instead

Comment: It seems that `text` argument is passed by `TextInput` component class which also registers custom event `onChangeText`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're passing a reference to a function that has the same signature.

[React function reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) may help shed some light.

given

```
callback = param => { /* do stuff */ };
```

then

```
componentFn={callback};
```

is equivalent to

```
componentFn = param => { /* do stuff */ };
```

but

```
componentFn={param => callback(param)}
```

is equivalent to

```
component = param => { callback(param) } // call function that does stuff
```

direct reference just removes a middle function binding.

Answer (score -1):

Need to pass the text input to the handleChangeInput

```
<View>    
<TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
onChangeText={(text) =>{this.handleChangeInput(text)}} value={input}/>   
</View>
or set directly the change text value
<TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({input:text})} value={input}/>
```

Comment: While nearly equivalent, it doesn't answer OPs question as to why it's not required to do this.  For example, this will bind a new function on every render cycle which has some performance overhead.  When a callback function has the same signature and the component's function, you can directly reference it.